# How to correctly convert into a Date object this "strange" cell value retrieve parsing an Excel using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I am going crazy trying to parse an Excel from Java using **Apache POI** and I ami finding the following problem parsing a specific column containin dates.

This is the column into my Excel file:

[image]

As you can see this column contains date fields but some cells of this column contains **number** values some other celles contains **text** values (I can see it using the **TYPE()** Excel function). I really don't know how it is possible because all the cell contains date fields. Some idea?

Anyway in my code I am trying to handle this strange situation in this way:

```
if(currentRow.getCell(20) != null && !currentRow.getCell(20).toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
    
    if(currentRow.getCell(20).getCellType().toString().equals("STRING")) {
        System.out.println("Data sottoscrizione contratto è STRING: " + currentRow.getCell(20).toString());
        
    }
    else if(currentRow.getCell(20).getCellType().toString().equals("NUMERIC")) {
        System.out.println("Data sottoscrizione contratto è NUMERIC");
        String dateAsString = currentRow.getCell(20).toString();
        System.out.println("DATA SOTTOSCRIZIONE CONTRATTO: " + currentRow.getCell(20).toString());
        
        
    }
}
```

In this way I can handle both the case trying to convert to a date.

And here my problem. When it found an Excel numeric value in enter into the if **NUMERIC** case

and printing the cell value by:

```
System.out.println("DATA SOTTOSCRIZIONE CONTRATTO: " + currentRow.getCell(20).toString());
```

I obtain printed the value **16-ott-2017** related to the date value **16/10/2017**

And here some doubts: Why am I obtaining in this format instead something like **16/10/2017**.

**16-ott-2017** should be the italian formattation of the date. How can I convert it into a propper Date object?

Comment: There's [`Cell.getDateCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue--) which you should be using if you directly want to receive a `java.util.Date`. However, this isn't up to date, so you could as well use [`Cell.getLocalDateTimeValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getLocalDateTimeCellValue--) and format it as desired by using a `java.time.DateTimeFormatter`. You are currently using the `toString()` of a cell, which will not (always) give you the underlying value.

Comment: @deHaar it works for the numeric case but for the cell containing text it go into an exception

Comment: Yes, for text, use `getStringCellValue()` and maybe convert it via `LocalDate.parse(DateTImeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.ITALIAN)` if the `String` is of that pattern...

Comment: if you put it as answer I will be happy to accept it

Comment: Sure... May take some minutes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buon giorno!

You are currently using the `toString()` method of the cell, which will not be very accurate in returning numeric values or even dates. It might work sometimes, but it won't do always.

Use the methods that get you a real value, like [`Cell.getNumericCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue--), [`Cell.getDateCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getDateCellValue--) (outdated because it returns a `java.util.Date`) or [`Cell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getLocalDateTimeCellValue--). If your cell just contains text, like `"16-ott-2020"`, use the [`getStringCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue--) and convert the value returned to a `LocalDate` (or `LocalDateTime` depends on if *time of day* matters for you).

Here's an example of the conversion (to a `LocalDate`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // assuming you alread received the value as String
    String cellStringValue = "16-ott-2020";
    // provice a formatter that can parse Italian month names (or days of week)
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.ITALIAN);
    // parse the String to a LocalDate
    LocalDate sediciOttobreDuemilaEVenti = LocalDate.parse(cellStringValue, dtf);
    // and print its default value
    System.out.println(sediciOttobreDuemilaEVenti);
    // alternatively use the same formatter for output
    System.out.println(sediciOttobreDuemilaEVenti.format(dtf));
}
```

The output of that code is

```
2020-10-16
16-ott-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case NUMERIC:
                if(Cell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue()!=null) {
                    LocalDateTime actualdate = Cell.getLocalDateTimeCellValue();
                    String formattedDate = actualdate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));
                    System.out.println(formattedDate);

                }
                break;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (Cell.getCellType()) {
            case STRING: 
                 System.out.print(Cell.getStringCellValue());
                 break;
            case NUMERIC:
                DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                String CellValue = df.formatCellValue(Cell);
                System.out.println(CellValue);
                break;
            case BOOLEAN: 
                System.out.print(Cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;          
            
            case BLANK:
                System.out.println("");
            }   
            System.out.print(" | ");
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).